# Convert List into a integer or float

Tags: python-2.7, list, integer

so i'm having a problem converting to a list to integer or float. what i mean in converting is like this. i have a list that has one element.

```
newList = ['2.0G']
```

i want that to convert into this

```
numFloat = 2.0
```

or

```
numInt = 2
```

i tried regex to extract the number from string so i can assign it to another variable

```
firstVariable = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", newList[0])
```

i have to keep calling the index in firstVariable to access the `2.0` or `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work ?

```
newList = ['2.0G']
numFloat = ''.join([i for i in newList[0] if i.isdigit() or i == '.'])
print(numFloat)
```

The above code will print `2.0`  to the console.

What I am doing here,  is that I am going through each and every item in the first item of the list , and then checking if its a `digit` or a `.`. If its not any one of these I move to the next character.

Please note that I am doing `newList[0]` because you mentioned that your list has only one element.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Thanks.

Comment: i tried it but the output is ```20``` it doesn't recognized the decimal point. but i think i can start with this, thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with a new code.. Please check now.